# How to consistently get ASCII-8BIT encoding in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

Ruby seems a bit inconsistent in its handling of encodings:

```
irb -E BINARY:BINARY
irb(main):001:0> "hi".encoding
=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

So that "works". Now what about plain `ruby`?

```
ruby -E BINARY:BINARY -e 'p "hi".encoding'
#<Encoding:US-ASCII>
```

That doesn't work. Furthermore, when `p "hi".encoding` is placed in `x.rb`, the output of `ruby -E BINARY:BINARY x.rb` is:

```
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

How do I get `ASCII-8BIT` literals when invoking `ruby`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals have the same encoding as the script encoding. Instead of `'hi'.encoding` you can use the keyword `__ENCODING__` to retrieve it. The script encoding can be changed by putting a magic comment at the beginning of your script:

```
# encoding: ASCII-8BIT

p __ENCODING__ # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

The `-E` flag of `ruby` doesn't affect the encoding of string literals. It's only for changing the external and internal encoding. You can read about the various type of encodings and their purpose in the [`Encoding`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Encoding.html) documentation.

Back to the encoding of string literals: Even though `irb` claims its `-E` flag is the "Same as `ruby -E`" that isn't true. It uses the external encoding as script encoding. `irb` already has several limitations. This could be one of them. It's at least a documentation bug.

Besides the magic comment there's another discouraged way to set the script encoding via `ruby`: the `-K` flag and the `n` (none) kcode. `ruby -Kne "p __ENCODING__"` should print `#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>`. However `-K` also changes the external encoding.

Comment: Lots of good info here, thanks for this! I think I will use the magic comment approach. Just found out about `frozen_string_literal` as well.